# Get frequency of different combinations in r with binary data

Tags: r, count, combinations

I have a table with binary data which looks like this:

```
middle-circle   triangles-inside    straight-rays   split-rays  triangle-rays   grouped-rays   sep-lines    
1                       0                  0            0            1                0            1
0                       1                  0            1            0                0            0
0                       0                  0            0            0                0            0
0                       1                  0            1            0                0            0
0                       1                  0            1            0                0            0
0                       0                  0            0            0                0            0 
0                       0                  1            0            0                0            0
```

I want to find out how often different combinations occur.
I was reading about the same problem here on stackoverflow and I applied the following code to my data:

```
library(gtools)
# get all vars present in each row
present <- lapply(seq(nrow(det)), function(i) names(which(det[i,] == 1)))
# get all pairs
all.pairs <- gtools::combinations(n = ncol(det), r = 2, colnames(det))
# count times pairs appear
count <- apply(all.pairs, 1, function(x){
  there <- lapply(x, function(y) sapply(present, `%in%`, x = y))
  sum(Reduce(`&`, there))
})

cbind(all.pairs, count)
```

I get the following result:

```
                                            count
 [1,] "grouped_rays"     "middle_circle"    "0"  
 [2,] "grouped_rays"     "separation_lines" "0"  
 [3,] "grouped_rays"     "split _rays"      "0"  
 [4,] "grouped_rays"     "straight_rays"    "0"  
 [5,] "grouped_rays"     "triangle_rays"    "0"  
 [6,] "grouped_rays"     "triangles_inside" "0"  
 [7,] "middle_circle"    "separation_lines" "0"  
 [8,] "middle_circle"    "split _rays"      "0"  
 [9,] "middle_circle"    "straight_rays"    "0"  
[10,] "middle_circle"    "triangle_rays"    "0"  
[11,] "middle_circle"    "triangles_inside" "0"  
[12,] "separation_lines" "split _rays"      "0"  
[13,] "separation_lines" "straight_rays"    "0"  
[14,] "separation_lines" "triangle_rays"    "0"  
[15,] "separation_lines" "triangles_inside" "0"  
[16,] "split _rays"      "straight_rays"    "0"  
[17,] "split _rays"      "triangle_rays"    "0"  
[18,] "split _rays"      "triangles_inside" "0"  
[19,] "straight_rays"    "triangle_rays"    "0"  
[20,] "straight_rays"    "triangles_inside" "0"  
[21,] "triangle_rays"    "triangles_inside" "0"
```

My questions: Is there a possibility to not only get pairs of combinations but all combinations?
Why does it always say "count 0"?
I am trying to get a list like the one above with all combinations possible and the count of how often they occur.
It should look like this:

```
                                                                   count
 [1,] "grouped_rays"     "middle_circle"     "sep-lines             "2"  
 [2,] "grouped_rays"     "separation_lines"  "triangles inside"     "0"  
 [3,] "grouped_rays"     "split _rays"                              "1"
```

And, of course, all other combinations that are possible. This is just an example.

Comment: what's your expected final output?

Comment: I want to know how often different combinations occur in the dataframe.

Comment: You should define what kind of object you expect to get at the end. Can you show the exact output for this specific case? You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this give the desired result?

```
tt <- do.call(rbind, apply(x==1, 1, function(y) {
  z <- names(y[y])
  if(length(z) > 1) t(combn(z, 2))}))
table(apply(tt, 1, function(y) paste(sort(y), collapse = " ")))
#   middle.circle sep.lines middle.circle triangle.rays 
#                          1                           1 
#    sep.lines triangle.rays split.rays triangles.inside 
#                          1                           3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try the code: 
dim(X) must have a positive length